# Entity Framework Core: one-to-one relation required

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

Entities: `Address` and `Market`:

```
public class Address
{
    ...

    // Navigation properties
    public Guid MarketId { get; set; }
    public Market Market { get; set; }
}

public class Market
{
    ...

    // Navigation properties
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

Relation rules:

1. Each `Market` has an `Address` and a `Market` cannot exist without an `Address`. `Address` is required
2. The user cannot delete an `Address` that belongs to a `Market`
3. When the user deletes a `Market`, its `Address` must be deleted automatically

Is it possible to configure the above relation with Entity Framework Core and Fluent API?

I've read about one-to-one relationships with EF Core and I learned that I need to say which entity is the principal and which is the dependent. And I must use Fluent API to do that.

I've tried two approaches:

1. Market as principal: with this approach, only rule 3 is valid. I can add a `Market` without an `Address` (breaks the rule 1). An existing `Market` is needed to add an `Address`. And the user can delete the `Address` that belongs to a `Market` (breaks the rule 2).

```
builder.Entity<Market>()
  .HasOne<Address>(m => m.Address)
  .WithOne(a => a.Market)
  .HasForeignKey<Address>(a => a.MarketId)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

2. `Address` as principal: with this approach, only the rule 3 is broken. The user cannot add a `Market` without an `Address`, in other words, an existing `Address` is needed to add a `Market`. The user cannot delete an `Address` that belongs to a `Market` because on the DeleteBehavior, the relation was set as Restrict. But if the user deletes a `Market`, its `Address` won't be deleted automatically. The API must handle that.

```
builder.Entity<Market>()
  .HasOne<Address>(m => m.Address)
  .WithOne(a => a.Market)
  .HasForeignKey<Market>(m => m.AddressId)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

I'm not sure if I've set the relations correctly or if it's just an EF Core  limitation. Any help?

Comment: Sounds like [Owned Enttiy Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)  would also be a good fit.

Comment: EF core is totally unequipped in the area of required one-to-one relationships. One-to-one, table splitting, owned type, they all have problems enforcing the required child or dependent entity. Maybe it's because a relational database can't enforce it, but at least EF could *validate* it.

Answer (score -1):

The Fluent API should not be able to meet your current needs, because your needs are `contrary` to normal needs.

According to normal logic, `Address` is the main table,  it not be attached to the `Market` table, so when you delete the `Market` table data, you should not affect the `Address` table.

However, if you must delete, you have two other alternatives.

The first one is to delete the corresponding data directly `in the code logic after you delete the Market's data`, you can get the Address data according to the currently deleted Market data's foreign key `AddressId` and then delete it.

Second, you can create a `trigger` in the database to ensure that when deleting Market data, the corresponding Address data is also deleted, the logic is the same as the first.